# How to get ASCII/EBCDIC character in IBM db2 iSeries

Tags: db2, ibm-midrange

I want to get character quote(`'`) and double quote(`"`) ASCII/EBCDIC, in IBM DB2 iSeries. 
Honestly i don't know what exactly iSeries supports - ASCII or EBCDIC. I'm trying both, but no luck.

http://www.simotime.com/asc2ebc1.htm

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc/doc/r0010873.htm

Example: get (A) character

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE CUSTOMER_NAME LIKE '%' + CHR(065) + '%'

SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE CUSTOMER_NAME LIKE '%' + CHR(41) + '%'

SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE CUSTOMER_NAME LIKE '%' + CHR(193) + '%'
```

Gives me this error:

> SQL0204 - CHR in *LIBL type *N not found.

Comment: Firstly i want to know how to get character ascii/ebcdic and then use it for later use and u know IBM DB2 iSeries doesn't support regular expression.

Answer (score 4):

If you are simply trying to put a single quote (apostrophe) in your string delimited by single quotes, you need to double it, like this `'%''%'`.  If you want to concatenate, use `||` (in unix, known as 2 "pipe" characters), not `+` (plus).  You didn't need hex in your example, but if you had, the way to do it would have been `x'C1'` (an 'A' in EBCDIC).

iSeries uses EBCDIC natively for most things in general.  There is a `char()` function.

Your link to online documentation is for DB2 on Linux, Unix, and Windows.  You want the [iSeries Information Center](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/eserver/ibmi.html) at http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/eserver/ibmi.html , or more specifically (depending on which OS release you are using)

- for [v5r4](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp), see [DB2 for i5/OS SQL Reference](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r4/index.jsp?topic=%2Fdb2%2Frbafzmst02.htm)
- for [i 6.1](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v6r1m0/index.jsp), see [DB2 for i SQL Reference](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/db2/rbafzintro.htm)
- for [i 7.1](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp), see
  [DB2 for i SQL Reference](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fdb2%2Frbafzintro.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Here's some basic information on SQL [character conversion](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp) that may be helpful.

This footnote pretty much sums it up:

*"Character conversion, when required, is automatic and is transparent to the application when it is successful. A knowledge of conversion is, therefore, unnecessary when all the strings involved in a statement’s execution are represented in the same way. Thus, for many readers, character conversion may be irrelevant"*

The [CHR](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v6r1m0/topic/db2/rbafzscachr.htm) function was added in V6R1.

Coding to a specific character set is not good practice however you can perform character translation within an HLL using the [QDCXLATE](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fapis%2FQDCXLATE.htm) API.

Comment: QDCXLATE was essentially obsoleted when Unicode became relatively ubiquitous. The [iconv() APIs](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/apis/iconv.htm) are preferred since maybe V3R1.

Comment: I agree with the last comment. According to Bob Cozzi "using QDCXLATE to convert between these two fundamental character sets should be avoided." (http://www.mcpressonline.com/programming/rpg/converting-between-character-sets)